# Java - read a file line by line till the end of the file

Tags: java, file, input, graph, format

I'm working on a project that requires me to find the Minimum Spanning Tree of a given graph, in Java. I'm quite a Java noob, as I have mostly used C++.

I have written the algorithm, but there's a unique type of input format, which is kind of like this:

```
0 1:33 2:0 3:12 4:29 5:32 6:22 7:13 8:45 9:21
1 0:6 2:18 3:2 4:26 5:41 6:8 7:47 8:13 9:19
2 0:22 1:28 3:49 4:47 5:5 6:16 7:32 8:5 9:34
3 0:21 1:24 2:2 4:29 5:20 6:39 7:17 8:21 9:3
4 0:27 1:20 2:38 3:4 5:14 6:25 7:0 8:24 9:11
5 0:20 1:7 2:29 3:15 4:3 6:19 7:11 8:19 9:41
6 0:14 1:36 2:6 3:45 4:18 5:33 7:43 8:22 9:36
7 0:25 1:12 2:15 3:45 4:18 5:43 6:41 8:37 9:26
8 0:29 1:44 2:23 3:15 4:34 5:45 6:27 7:29 9:4
9 0:18 1:41 2:20 3:25 4:18 5:10 6:10 7:49 8:42
```

or, more clearly:

```
[source-vertex] [destination-vertex]:[weight] [destination-vertex]:[weight] ...
```

What I would like to know is how can I read this kind of input format?

I was thinking of reading each line until the file ends, and then parse the numbers from each line.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So, any problems with the code you've tried so far (that reads the file and then parses it) ?

Comment: Since Java 8, you can use [`Files.readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) (give it a try and come back to us if you've encountered any issue)

Comment: Yes you have to do it the way you are thinking, let's show what have you done so far.

Comment: @Shark I have not tried doing that already, because I'm not familiar with the syntax. I'm looking for different sources to see how I can do this now, though.

Comment: @Thoomas I will try, thank you!

Comment: Extend the abstract class Reader using BufferedReader as a model. Include the line separator characters.

Comment: @Thoomas This works, thank you, but I have another question. Since the input file might be quite big, is there any way to read one line at the time and not keep the entire lines in a List?

Comment: @hiimsoba You can use a `BufferedReader` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you basically have two questions:

- **how to read a file line by line**: there's many ways to do that (some convenience APIs in Java8+), the classic way is to get a `Reader` and read from an `InputStream` with the propert text *encoding*, using *try-with-resources*.
- **how to read structured data**: simplest way is to use *regular expressions* to extract the data.

Code to read the data according to your format:

```
File f = ... // file to read

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

    // regular expression checking the format of each line
    Pattern linePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(?:\\s+(\\d+):(\\d+))*");
    // regular expression to find the index (first number) in a line
    Pattern indexPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
    // regular expression to find the vertices (a:b) in a line
    Pattern relationPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+):(\\d+)");

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        if (linePattern.matcher(line).matches()) {

            Matcher indexMatcher = indexPattern.matcher(line);
            if (indexMatcher.find()) {
                int sourceVertex = Integer.parseInt(indexMatcher.group(1));
                // do something with the sourceVertex 

                Matcher relationMatcher = relationPattern.matcher(line);
                while (relationMatcher.find()) {
                    int destinationVertex = Integer.parseInt(relationMatcher.group(1));
                    int weight = Integer.parseInt(relationMatcher.group(2));
                    // do something with destinationVertex and weight
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Steam API and loading your file with a BuferedReader and sing the lines() method. This results in a Stream which you can then manipulate as you want.